# Switch statement throws error

Tags: r

I would like to use a switch statement to convert a number. If the case is 1 the number should be 13, case 2 should be 14 etc...

Therefore I wrote the following statement:

```
 settime <- function(time){
     switch(time,
            "1" = 13,
            2 = 14, 
            3 = 15,
            4 = 16,
            5 = 17,
            6 = 18,
            7 = 19,
            8 = 20,
            9 = 21,
            10 = 22,
            11 = 23,
            12 = 24)
   }
```

This however gives me the following error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:  "    switch(time,
>          1 ="

Any thought on where I go wrong?

Comment: what the reason for defining a function that is actually switch ? you don't need quotes around the `1` and morover you actually must not put all numbers. Actually your function with parameter `time` is doing the same as `switch(time, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, ...)`. Now why you don't just do `time+12` is another question. (the error you're getting is because you've not put quotes around the other numbers. So either time is a character variable and you must put quotes everywhere or it's numeric and you don't put the numbers at all). `?switch` could help you on this one

Comment: [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why not use `(13:24)[match(time,1:12)]` ?

Comment: I agree with posters, if you just want to change values, switch may not be the base venue for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more obvious way to get what you want is with `time + 12`.
It is simpler than `switch` and allows you to pass a vector and not just a value.

But as your problem might be more complicated than the one you put in your example and if you feel you need to use switch (for which you can pass only one value at a time), and to complete my comment, you have 2 options to do that, as stated in the below sample from `help(switch)`:

> switch works in two distinct ways depending whether the first argument
>   evaluates to a character string or a number.
>
> If the value of EXPR is not a character string it is coerced to
>   integer. Note that this also happens for factors, with a warning, as
>   typically the character level is meant. If the integer is between 1
>   and nargs()-1 then the corresponding element of ... is evaluated and
>   the result returned: thus if the first argument is 3 then the fourth
>   argument is evaluated and returned.
>
> If EXPR evaluates to a character string then that string is matched
>   (exactly) to the names of the elements in .... If there is a match
>   then that element is evaluated unless it is missing, in which case the
>   next non-missing element is evaluated, so for example switch("cc", a =
>   1, cc =, cd =, d = 2) evaluates to 2. If there is more than one match,
>   the first matching element is used. In the case of no match, if there
>   is a unnamed element of ... its value is returned. (If there is more
>   than one such argument an error is returned.)

Either time is a character variable:

```
time <- "3"
switch(time, "1"=13, "2"=14, "3"=15, "4"=16)
# [1] 15
```

Or time is numeric:

```
time <- 3
switch(time, 13, 14, 15, 16)
# [1] 15
```

Comment: I get error by using your first statement (even after converting to 'character'.

Comment: @akrun either it is because you're using switch with a vector (switch is not vectorised) or because your variable is not in the 4 values I have put (I didn't put all 12 values but only 4 for the example syntax)

Comment: I created a full set of values with `switch`.  Why don't you show a reproducible example?

Comment: @akrun I posted an answer to correct the OP syntax, the example is the syntax itself

Comment: @akrun I took the `time` variable name from the OP and use it in my example syntax. you can do `time <- "3"` if you want to test it

Comment: Okay, so if there is a vector of values, then it has to be looped on.  It is worse than I thought.

Comment: @akrun, I'm not answering your problem, I'm correcting the OP syntax for `switch`: `switch("3", "1"=13, 2=14)` throws an error, `switch("2", "1"=13, "2"=14)` or `switch(2, 13, 14)` don't. The problem wasn't about `switch` not being vectorised. Like zx8754 stated, this is very likely an x/y problem. We don't have the x part, I'm trying to give the OP some hints about the y part

Answer (score 2):

We could do this without using any `switch`.  I am not sure how efficient `switch` will be for large vectors.  But, the below method should be fast enough.

```
 res <- setNames(13:24, 1:12)[as.character(v1)]
 res
 #4  3  9  7  8 12  4 10 10  4  8  5  9  9  4 11  3  1  7  2  2  7  9  2  3  9 
 #16 15 21 19 20 24 16 22 22 16 20 17 21 21 16 23 15 13 19 14 14 19 21 14 15 21
```

From the above, it is easier to remove the `name`.

```
 unname(res)
```

Or

```
 as.vector(res)
```

We do not need to use `as.character` as the elements start from 1:12.  But, in case, it is a different vector, then we may need to be extra careful.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(1:12, 30, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: so, if you don't want to use switch here, you really believe that `setNames/unname` is better than just an addition (`v1+12`)?

Comment: @Cath I believe the OP used a simple example to show the problem.  But, in real case, it may be a bit more complex.  Given that, the OP's original data is complex, `setName/unname` or `match` would be faster than `switch` IMHO.